# Where is the data stored when we implement Blackberry persistent apis to store data?

Tags: blackberry, persistence

Where does the data get stored when we use a Blackberry Persistent store to save data in our applications?
Is it the removable sd card or device memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stored in the device memory (built-in flash memory).

Comment: Novakowaski: can we able to see that data ?

Comment: Not that I know of, other than by using the Persistent store API